# ¿Cómo hago para sacar toda la lista de películas de una página?

Tags: python, lista, scraping

necesito pasar toda la lista de peliculas de una página y luego imprimir en python, la web es esta:
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/view-all/blocks/1523534

Me pasaron este codigo que funciona bien para sacar el nombre de la primer película:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

PATH = '/Users/maxi_/Desktop/Driver/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.starz.com/ar/es/view-all/blocks/1523534")   

time.sleep(5)

pelicula = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/starz-root/div/div[1]/section/starz- 
view-all/div/div/div/div/section[1]/virtual-scroller/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/starz- 
content-item/article/div[1]/a[1]/h3').get_attribute('textContent')

driver.quit()
print (pelicula)
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Para comenzar, tienes que tener en cuenta que efectivamente vas a estar mostrando una(1) sola pelicula, ya que estás utilizando *find_element* en lugar de *find_elements*. Como verás estás utilizando *xpath*, y puede volverse poco entendible, más si estás iniciando.

Partiendo desde el xpath propuesto en tu código, se puede resolver el problema, pero como te decía es muy confuso. Identificar el elemento por *xpath* es cómo tener un array de 5 elementos y que solo estes apuntando al primer elemento, entonces aquí solo quedaría *iterar*.

*'/html/body/starz-root/div/div[1]/section/starz-view-all/div/div/div/div/section[1]/virtual-scroller/div[2]/div[**`1`**]/div[**`1`**]/div/starz-content-item/article/div[1]/a[1]/h3'*

Fijate que en el xpath te marqué los dos elementos que hay que iterar.. tocando un poco y observando como es la página, se puede apreciar que el primero llega hasta el 24, y el segundo hasta el 4. Entonces para poder obtener todos los nombres de las peliculas, solo tenemos que hacer un bucle que vaya hasta el 24 y otro que vaya hasta el 4...

```
for X in range(1,25):
    for Y in range(1,5):
        xpath = f'/html/body/starz-root/div/div[1]/section/starz-view-all/div/div/div/div/section[1]/virtual-scroller/div[2]/div[{X}]/div[{Y}]/div/starz-content-item/article/div[1]/a[1]/h3'
        foo = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).get_attribute('textContent')
        print(foo)
```

output:

```
El sorprendente Hombre-Araña 2 - La amenaza de Electro
Mamma Mia!
John Wick 2: Un nuevo día para matar
Más fuerte que el destino
Oscura seducción
Spider-Man: De regreso a casa
Jumanji: En la selva
El Karate Kid
La enfermera
Anna Karenina
12 Horas
Elizabeth: La edad de oro
La reina
47 Ronin
El duende 2
La novia de mi mejor amigo
Cartas a Julieta
Son como niños 2
Siniestro
Después Del Sexo
El último cazador de brujas
Horizonte profundo
Dulce venganza
Maria Antonieta La Reina Adolescente
Whiplash: Música y obsesión
Una esposa de mentira
Crepúsculo La Saga: Amanecer - Parte 1
Zombie
Si no despierto
Hellraiser: Juicio
Día del atentado
Un paso adelante
Dulce venganza 2
Pandillas de Nueva York
Crank: muerte anunciada
Plan de escape
Dura verdad
El Príncipe y yo
La maldición de la casa Winchester
Dune
El Justiciero
Los mensajeros
Jerry Maguire: Amor y desafio
La redada
Apariciones
2012
Belly
Open Water
Pánico en altamar
Rapture-Palooza
Caracortada
De Tyler Perry: ¿Por qué nos casamos?
Crepúsculo la saga: Luna Nueva
Los juegos del hambre: Sinsajo - Parte 1
Los juegos del hambre: En llamas
El lado oscuro del deseo
Sicario
El grito 3
¡Bu! 2 Una noche de brujas de Madea, de Tyler Perry
Obsesión Del Pasado
Grey Lady
La cabaña
Extraordinario
Golpe en londres
Venganza letal
Rendirse jamás
Ali
Llámame Por Tu Nombre
De Tyler Perry: Las niñas de papá
Casino
Cubos
Al borde del abismo
La Guardería de Papá
Peligro en Bangkok
Educación básica
Rudo y Cursi : La vida es un volado
Crepúsculo, la saga: Eclipse
Pobres divas
De Tyler Perry: ¿Por qué me casé también?
Red 2
Crepúsculo la saga: Amanecer – Parte 2
Escándalo Americano
Divergente la serie: Insurgente
Escondida
Recuérdame
Retornados
Lugares oscuros
Dónde Está El Dinero
Campamento del terror
Jigsaw: El juego continúa
La maldición de Blackwood
Father Figures
Si Solo Pudiera Imaginar
Testigo de cargo
Querido Santa Secreto
La Cumbre Escarlata
```

Pero también se puede resolver tu problema utilizando un solo bucle y se hace utilizando `find_elements_by_class_name`, nos aprovechamos que también podemos acceder al elemento `a` y gracias a eso obtener el `href`. Entonces podemos mostrar nombre y link asociado:

```
for content in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('content-title'):
    tag_a = content.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
    print(tag_a.get_attribute('textContent'))
    print(tag_a.get_attribute('href'))
```

output

```
El sorprendente Hombre-Araña 2 - La amenaza de Electro
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/el-sorprendente-hombre-ara%C3%B1a-2-la-amenaza-de-electro-50064
Mamma Mia!
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/mamma-mia-50021
John Wick 2: Un nuevo día para matar
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/john-wick-2-un-nuevo-d%C3%ADa-para-matar-61327
Más fuerte que el destino
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/m%C3%A1s-fuerte-que-el-destino-62674
Oscura seducción
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/oscura-seducci%C3%B3n-60743
Spider-Man: De regreso a casa
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/spider-man-de-regreso-a-casa-37147
Jumanji: En la selva
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/jumanji-en-la-selva-38790
El Karate Kid
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/el-karate-kid-6462
La enfermera
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/la-enfermera-28990
Anna Karenina
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/anna-karenina-41102
12 Horas
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/12-horas-51692
Elizabeth: La edad de oro
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/elizabeth-la-edad-de-oro-65816
La reina
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/la-reina-25264
47 Ronin
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/47-ronin-52304
El duende 2
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/el-duende-2-25250
La novia de mi mejor amigo
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/la-novia-de-mi-mejor-amigo-50076
Cartas a Julieta
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/cartas-a-julieta-50199
Son como niños 2
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/son-como-ni%C3%B1os-2-50698
Siniestro
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/siniestro-51847
Después Del Sexo
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/despu%C3%A9s-del-sexo-51896
El último cazador de brujas
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/el-%C3%BAltimo-cazador-de-brujas-59242
Horizonte profundo
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/horizonte-profundo-62067
Dulce venganza
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/dulce-venganza-9303
Maria Antonieta La Reina Adolescente
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/maria-antonieta-la-reina-adolescente-14139
Whiplash: Música y obsesión
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/whiplash-m%C3%BAsica-y-obsesi%C3%B3n-23791
Una esposa de mentira
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/una-esposa-de-mentira-44132
Crepúsculo La Saga: Amanecer - Parte 1
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/crep%C3%BAsculo-la-saga-amanecer-parte-1-50666
Zombie
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/zombie-50752
Si no despierto
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/si-no-despierto-51601
Hellraiser: Juicio
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/hellraiser-juicio-62668
Día del atentado
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/d%C3%ADa-del-atentado-62672
Un paso adelante
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/un-paso-adelante-24244
Dulce venganza 2
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/dulce-venganza-2-25826
Pandillas de Nueva York
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/pandillas-de-nueva-york-29581
Crank: muerte anunciada
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/crank-muerte-anunciada-49809
Plan de escape
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/plan-de-escape-50202
Dura verdad
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/dura-verdad-50508
El Príncipe y yo
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/el-pr%C3%ADncipe-y-yo-52089
La maldición de la casa Winchester
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/la-maldici%C3%B3n-de-la-casa-winchester-62694
Dune
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/dune-6612
El Justiciero
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/el-justiciero-22163
Los mensajeros
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/los-mensajeros-29666
Jerry Maguire: Amor y desafio
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/jerry-maguire-amor-y-desafio-29696
La redada
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/la-redada-34897
Apariciones
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/apariciones-36016
2012
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/2012-37333
Belly
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/belly-39540
Open Water
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/open-water-41557
Pánico en altamar
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/p%C3%A1nico-en-altamar-41569
Rapture-Palooza
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/rapture-palooza-42964
Caracortada
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/caracortada-45072
De Tyler Perry: ¿Por qué nos casamos?
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/de-tyler-perry-por-qu%C3%A9-nos-casamos-50107
Crepúsculo la saga: Luna Nueva
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/crep%C3%BAsculo-la-saga-luna-nueva-50238
Los juegos del hambre: Sinsajo - Parte 1
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/los-juegos-del-hambre-sinsajo-parte-1-50738
Los juegos del hambre: En llamas
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/los-juegos-del-hambre-en-llamas-50815
El lado oscuro del deseo
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/el-lado-oscuro-del-deseo-50862
Sicario
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/sicario-50878
El grito 3
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/el-grito-3-51492
¡Bu! 2 Una noche de brujas de Madea, de Tyler Perry
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/bu-2-una-noche-de-brujas-de-madea-de-tyler-perry-51713
Obsesión Del Pasado
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/obsesi%C3%B3n-del-pasado-51729
Grey Lady
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/grey-lady-51947
La cabaña
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/la-caba%C3%B1a-57174
Extraordinario
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/extraordinario-62071
Golpe en londres
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/golpe-en-londres-62696
Venganza letal
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/venganza-letal-63738
Rendirse jamás
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/rendirse-jam%C3%A1s-30857
Ali
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/ali-37309
Llámame Por Tu Nombre
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/ll%C3%A1mame-por-tu-nombre-38894
De Tyler Perry: Las niñas de papá
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/de-tyler-perry-las-ni%C3%B1as-de-pap%C3%A1-39528
Casino
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/casino-43838
Cubos
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/cubos-47298
Al borde del abismo
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/al-borde-del-abismo-49297
La Guardería de Papá
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/la-guarder%C3%ADa-de-pap%C3%A1-49407
Peligro en Bangkok
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/peligro-en-bangkok-49853
Educación básica
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/educaci%C3%B3n-b%C3%A1sica-50122
Rudo y Cursi : La vida es un volado
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/rudo-y-cursi-la-vida-es-un-volado-50225
Crepúsculo, la saga: Eclipse
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/crep%C3%BAsculo-la-saga-eclipse-50241
Pobres divas
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/pobres-divas-50421
De Tyler Perry: ¿Por qué me casé también?
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/de-tyler-perry-por-qu%C3%A9-me-cas%C3%A9-tambi%C3%A9n-50512
Red 2
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/red-2-50631
Crepúsculo la saga: Amanecer – Parte 2
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/crep%C3%BAsculo-la-saga-amanecer-%E2%80%93-parte-2-50834
Escándalo Americano
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/esc%C3%A1ndalo-americano-50880
Divergente la serie: Insurgente
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/divergente-la-serie-insurgente-51081
Escondida
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/escondida-51619
Recuérdame
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/recu%C3%A9rdame-51833
Retornados
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/retornados-51836
Lugares oscuros
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/lugares-oscuros-52235
Dónde Está El Dinero
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/d%C3%B3nde-est%C3%A1-el-dinero-60447
Campamento del terror
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/campamento-del-terror-60727
Jigsaw: El juego continúa
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/jigsaw-el-juego-contin%C3%BAa-62688
La maldición de Blackwood
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/la-maldici%C3%B3n-de-blackwood-62692
Father Figures
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/father-figures-62698
Si Solo Pudiera Imaginar
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/si-solo-pudiera-imaginar-62700
Testigo de cargo
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/testigo-de-cargo-62754
Querido Santa Secreto
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/querido-santa-secreto-63449
La Cumbre Escarlata
https://www.starz.com/ar/es/movies/la-cumbre-escarlata-65822
```

En vez de mostrarlos puedes guardarlos en una lista o donde desees.

Para guardarlo en una *lista*, definimos una y agregamos cada registro en formato de lista. El resultado es conocido como una *Lista de listas*.

```
results = []
for content in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('content-title'):
        tag_a = content.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
        results.append([tag_a.get_attribute('textContent'),
                        tag_a.get_attribute('href')])
```

Comment: gracias lucas por haber respondido, en caso de que quisiera guardar la lista he probado este codigo junto al tuyo. pero solo me permitio cuando pido imprimir. no se que estará mal ?

Comment: como hago para poder guardarlos en una lista ?

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta